# Average value from xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml

What I want to do is to get the average value from xml node attributes with different time.
My xml is structured like this:

```
<logs>
  <log value="1" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 08:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="1" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 09:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="1" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="5" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 11:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="3" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 12:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="7" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 13:00 am CET"/>
  <log value="3" dateTime="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 14:00 am CET"/>
</log>
```

I want to calculate the average value from the last 5 hours, and write the value in label. My code is like this:

```
xdoc2.Load("data.xml");
 XmlNodeList n = xdoc2.GetElementsByTagName("log");
            List<int> values = new List<int>();
            foreach (XmlNode curr in n)
            {
                int date;
                date = Convert.ToInt32(curr.Attributes["dateTime"].InnerText);
                DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                if (date1.Hour != date1.Hour)
                   values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(curr.Attributes["value"].InnerText));
            }
            double average = values.Average();
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(average);
```

How can I add the condition for calculating the average value for the last 5 hours? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
var average = (from node in n
               let date = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["dateTime"].InnerText))
               orderby date 
               select Convert.ToInt32(curr.Attributes["value"].InnerText)
               .Take(5)
               .Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Dates with each other. For example:

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5);
        DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime("23.01.2013");
        if (d > d2){
            MessageBox.Show(d.ToString() + " " + d2.ToString());
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("nope");
        }
```

With comparison of dates, you can easily iterate through the xml and compare, if the date is smaller than DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5).

In your example it would be something like this:

```
 foreach (XmlNode curr in n)
        {
            int date;
            date = Convert.ToInt32(curr.Attributes["dateTime"].InnerText);
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5);
            if (date1>=now)
               values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(curr.Attributes["value"].InnerText));
        }
```

Afterwards you can just do the Average-Calculation like you have already done:

```
        double average = values.Average();
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5);
label4.Text = xdoc2.Descendants("log")
                   .Where(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Attribute("dateTime").Value, @"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a\m CE\T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > fromDate )
                   .Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("value").Value)).ToString();
```

Comment: don't know why, but the text in the label is still empty

Comment: your problem is convertion of datetime. you can see `Convert.ToDateTime("Sun, 09 Feb 2014 13:00 am CET")`. you need use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: so (x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Attribute("dateTime")) shall be (x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Attribute("dateTime")) ?

Comment: it gives error DateTime.ParseExact can take 1 argument

Comment: I'm getting close with your solution, so please tell me how can I fix this

Comment: your string format its not reasonable, example: `13:00 am`. you can Ignore extensions `am CET` like this: `DateTime.ParseExact(x.Attribute("dateTime").Value, @"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a\m CE\T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: i edited my answer. work? (Make sure that the dates are in the past 5 hours or add hours to minus).

Comment: and what about the text in the label?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string' error on .Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("value").Value));

Comment: Edited again... (Added `.ToString()` at end).